# Windows Service That reads From one table and inserts into another

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a windows service that will read records from one table and write them to another table. Problem is when i declare cmd = New SqlCommand(l_sSQL) the code  stop executing
but the service will still be running. I can insert into the other table using the service but i cant read from the other table.

Code Sample:

Private Sub dbcon()

```
Dim con As New SqlConnection
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
Dim ds As New DataSet

Dim x As String
Try
  con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=xxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=xxxxxxx"
  con.Open()
  cmd.Connection = con
  cmd = New SqlCommand()
  Dim i As Integer


  l_sSQL = "SELECT * ozekimessageout"
  cmd = New SqlCommand(l_sSQL)\\stops executing here
  adapter.SelectCommand = cmd
  adapter.Fill(ds)

  For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
    x = (ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(1))
```

next

End Sub

Please Help....

Answer (score 1):

Don't you need:  SELECT * **FROM** ozekimessageout

Plus:  You are 'newing' cmd twice, there is no need.

Comment: thanks for that i have made those changes but the problem still stays the same, the service runs but once i introduce

Comment: thanks for that i have made those changes but the problem still stays the same, the service runs but once i introduce sqladapter declaration it stops

Comment: thanks for that i have made those changes but the problem still stays the same, the service runs but once i introduce sqladapter declaration it stops Dim myReader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader() does windows service accept sql adapter?

Comment: Does the SQL statement run in a query window (like in SQL Management studio)?

Comment: Yes it does, the problem is here look.  cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ozekimessageout"
    cmd.Connection = con
    Dim myReader As SqlDataReader
    myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()\\HERE just when i put this line of code the service stops executing. this line myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

Comment: Does it run outside the service...could you create a small winform or console application and try it?  (I would suggest a permission issue but you say other data accessing parts are working.)

Comment: Hei, Since i could not manage to debug as i should i took your advice a bit further, so i did all my code from a console based app. and tested making sure it worked then just copied it into the service code and it works like magic. My problem is i want to be able to package this code and install on other machine is that possible like having an installation file for this service? I dont want it to run in debug mode on other machines u know. any ideas?

Comment: Glad it's working and you have a new development technique.  Since Installing a service is another topic I would suggest starting a new thread.

Comment: OK thanks Steve, i figured it out, just create an msi like we do for any other application. Thanks a LOADS for ur help.